# Zabbix 6.4 problem: can't connect to database MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, zabbix

I recently created a zabbix via this tuto: https://www.layerstack.com/resources/tutorials/How-to-install-ZABBIX-on-Ubuntu22
everything works until I accidentally delete zabbix-agent from my zabbix server and I launch the updates on it (apt update /upgrade) since I have this error message.

[image: 1]

I also have a problem of access to the MySQL database via terminal, I think of a problem of password but it is impossible to reset it via mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
If you have any ideas I'm interested.

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Thanks in advance

Comment: table `dbversion` was not found because the user cannot connect, see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-user-password/ to reset a passwrd